# IMG_load and TTF_OpenFont cause a segmentation fault using SDL2 on Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sdl-2

Recently I've been working on a project that uses SDL2 on Code::Blocks 10.03 on Debian. I need to load some PNG images and a font to write some things to screen. However, when I try to load the files, both IMG_load and TTF_OpenFont create a segmentation fault.

I am 100% sure the files are on the current path, as using incorrect filenames such as `buckt.png` instead of `bucket.png` result in both SDL_GetError and IMG_GetError returning "Couldn't open buckt.png", the same with TTF files; whereas if I use the correct filename, it causes the segfault. Interestingly enough, if I compile the project from the command line, using `g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf` it compiles and runs perfectly, but since I'm forced to use Code::Blocks, the terminal is not an option

For showcase, this snippet is located on the topmost part of the main function. As you may have guessed, on Code::Blocks, it won't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    TTF_Init();

    // The segfault is caused here, using Code::Blocks
    TTF_Font *gFont = TTF_OpenFont("LiberationMono-Bold.ttf",20); 
    if (gFont == NULL) {
        // This is never reached
        cout << "gFont is empty!" << endl;
    }

    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

And the execution working directory is set to `.`, which is the main folder for the Code::Blocks project, and also where the fonts and images are located.

If anyone has found a workaround to this situation, please let me know.

Comment: can you please show complete, compilable code?

Comment: @ChrisBeck Should the edit be enough to compile?

Comment: need to fix the using namespace std, but then it compiles with this line, and actually does not segfault for me `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf`

Comment: @ChrisBeck I know it compiles using the command line, the problem is it won't compile using Code::Blocks

Comment: well, did you try using a debugger? you could try to get a line number in SDL2 ttf i guess

Comment: one thing you can try, check exactly what version of SDL2_ttf you are linking with. There are SDL functions that you can use to get the version string for the version you compiled with, and the version you are linking with. It could be that your codeblocks is configured wrong. I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Both the compiled and linked versions are 2.0.12.

Comment: try running ldd on the binary?

Comment: Same thing, libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0

Comment: @Vicyorus *Code::Blocks, it won't work.*  Code::Blocks is not a compiler.  It is an IDE that uses (by default) `g++` to compile your code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am aware that g++ is the compiler and C::B is the IDE, however, the problem doesn't seem to originate on g++, it originates on C::B

Comment: @Vicyorus So you're saying the program is built successfully when you use CodeBlocks?  No syntax errors and the link is successful?  Then why would you say it is a CodeBlocks issue?  Also, when you compile a program using CodeBlocks, there is no "verboise" option that shows the exact compile and link commands being used?

Comment: @Vicyorus: does the crash happen when you *don't* have the font, or is it only when you do have the font? SDL_ttf is a fairly buggy library that is known to segfault if you give it hard cases. It might just not be able to handle the font that you are using.

Comment: Well, barter me and fry me on a skillet, either a restart or a clean reinstallation of SDL_image and SDL_ttf was all I needed. Thanks for the help anyways, @ChrisBeck